# Interactively animating the iOS chevron symbol

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uikit, interactive

I'm hoping to understand how the chevron symbol is interactively animated throughout iOS. Ideally this would be done using `UIViewPropertyAnimator` so that the animation's progress could be updated with a fraction. Attached is an occurrence of the animation in the operating system; any help is greatly appreciated.

[image: chevron animation]

Comment: A general way to handle something like this is to store all animations in a UIPropertyAnimator like you suggested, then you can update the fractionComplete value of the animation object as the scrollView content offset changes.  To get a positive or negative change in offset (to forward or reverse the animation) you subtract the last offset by the current offset reported in the "didscroll" delegate method.

Comment: I understand that part already. What I'm trying to understand is how to create the pointed chevron view that can move between the flattened and pointed states.

Comment: Ah, ok.  I myself would just make two CALayer objects, each drawing a line and have the anchor-point at the left and right edge respectively, then apply a rotation transformation to each layer to rotate the necessary degrees around the anchor point.  I've done that to animate clock hands before, but it could work to bend and flatten what would appear to be a single line (but what is actually two lines).

Comment: Following up on my previous comment, I realize if you want to use the UIViewPropertyAnimator, then CALayers isn't a great suggestion, but you could essentially do the same thing, you'd just need two views, each the same length as the other and overlapping, but each with only half the frame filled in, then just apply a basic rotation transform, which will rotate around the center of the view.